# Observing drift of a Levy process

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

It is a well known fact, that it is very difficult to estimate the drift of a Brownian motion with drift from looking at a single path over a finite interval $[0, T]$. Is it the case with Levy processes with jumps?

Assume we are given a Levy process with drift $\gamma$ and Levy measure $\nu$, with no Gaussian component. And we are given a single path over a finite interval $[0, T]$ of this process. Is it possible to determine $\gamma$ without knowing the parameters?

If the process is compound Poisson then it seems that the answer is YES - because there are intervals of strictly positive length without jumps, which we can use to read the drift. What is the answer for processes with infinite activity? Finite/infinite variation?

Comment: When you say that you are given a path of the process, I think that you mean over a finite time horizon only, otherwise it is always possible to determine the drift, even with a Brownian component.

Comment: If you are given the Levy measure then, yes, you can ways determine the drift by subtracting out the compensated jumps, which converges almost surely and leaves you just with the constant drift.

Comment: Hi @George, I added the information that the interval is finite - this was obviously my intention. Is your comment still true, even if the process has infinite activity?

Comment: @Grzenio: Yes, every Levy process is the sum of (i) A Brownian motion term, (ii) the sum of jumps bigger than 1, (iii) the sum over compensated jumps less than 1 and (iv) a constant drift. The only reason you split out the jumps bigger than one is because they might not be integrable, so that they can't be compensated. The sum in (iii) converges almost-surely (with a little care about the order of summation), but not absolutely. Furthermore, the compensator of the jumps is determined by the Levy measure.

Comment: @Grzenio: Protter and Jacod have written a book about semi martingale discretizations with numerous LLN and CLT which might have application for Lévy processes. Though I think that there is work to do to be able to apply their results to a practical case. Best regards. Here is a (commercial) link http://www.amazon.ca/Discretization-Processes-Jean-Jacod/dp/3642241263

Comment: I should write an actual answer to this question, rather than just leaving a comment. I'll do that when I get the time.

Comment: @George, the bit I still don't understand is the bit of the drift that results from the compensated small jumps, especially for processes with infinite variation, e.g gamma process. Because then the process jumps up infinitely often and kind of drifts down, so that the average growth rate is finite. How does it change if we add some drift to it?